# About a definition of an algebra over a field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I'm reading page 122 of Amann's [Analysis I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b137107).

---

A $K$-vector space $\mathcal{A}$ together with an operation
$$
\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}, \quad(a, b) \mapsto a \odot b
$$
is called an **algebra** over $K$ if the following hold:

- A1: $(\mathcal{A},+, \odot)$ is a ring.
- A2: The distributive law holds:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  &(\lambda a+\mu b) \odot c=\lambda(a \odot c)+\mu(b \odot c) \\
  &a \odot(\lambda b+\mu c)=\lambda(a \odot b)+\mu(a \odot c)
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  for all $a, b, c \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\lambda, \mu \in K$.

For the **ring multiplication $\odot$ in $\mathcal{A}$**, we again write $a b$ instead of $a \odot b$. This leads to no misunderstanding since it is always clear from context which multiplication is intended. This notation is also justified by the distributive laws which hold in $\mathcal{A}$. In general, the algebra (that is, the ring $(\mathcal{A}, \odot)$ ) is neither commutative nor contains a unity element.

---

**My understanding:** Because $(\mathcal{A},+, \odot)$ is a ring, we already have $(\lambda a+\mu b) \odot c = (\lambda a) \odot c + (\mu b) \odot c$. Then the distributive law A2 can be reduced to
$$
(\lambda a) \odot c= a \odot ( \lambda c) =\lambda(a \odot c)
$$
for all $a, c \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\lambda\in K$.

> Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: This is right! :)